# How to handle HTML Strings in Cocoa Touch

Tags: cocoa-touch, string, object

I'm using a RSS Reader and works fine when I tap the `UITableViewCell` to load the `<link>` either in a `UIWebView` or to open Safari on that link.

But I really want to learn how to load the Topic content into the application instead showing the entire site or jump to Safari

In the RSS feed per each `<item>` there is a `<body>` tag (and a `<Description>` that contains the same but encoded) that contains the topic content, like the image below shows:

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-13_0953.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2010-04-13_0953.png)

So, instead of catching the `<link>` I'm assigning the `<body>`. Problem is that it does not work correctly :-(

for this example I only get the content until the first `<br>` nothing more.

- I'm using a `NSString` as I would use in C#, should I use any other object, is there a better object to use on such data?
- Should I use an `UITextView` to load this information (as it has scroll already) or I should use a `UIWebView` instead?

Thank you.

---

**added**

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{            
    //NSLog(@"found this element: %@", elementName);
    currentElement = [elementName copy];
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        // clear out our story item caches...
        item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        currentTitle = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentDate = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentSummary = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentLink = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        currentBody = [NSMutableString new];  // added by me
        currentCreator = [NSMutableString new];  // added by me
    }       
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{     
    //NSLog(@"ended element: %@", elementName);
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        // save values to an item, then store that item into the array...
        [item setObject:currentTitle forKey:@"title"];
        [item setObject:currentLink forKey:@"link"];
        [item setObject:currentSummary forKey:@"summary"];
        [item setObject:currentDate forKey:@"date"];
        [item setObject:currentBody forKey:@"body"]; // <----
        [item setObject:currentCreator forKey:@"dc:creator"];

        [stories addObject:[item copy]];
        NSLog(@"adding story: %@", currentTitle);
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    //NSLog(@"found characters: %@", string);
    // save the characters for the current item...
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [currentTitle appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [currentLink appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"summary"]) {
        [currentSummary appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
        [currentDate appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"body"]) {
        [currentBody appendString:string]; // <----
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"dc:creator"]) {
        [currentCreator appendString:string];
    }
}
```

and to pass to my WebBrowser View I have:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Navigation logic

int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];

NSString * storyContent = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"body"];

// load web view
[self showWebPage:storyContent]; // <-- Here (storyContent variable) I only have the content until the first <br> :-(
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [SeismicXML](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html) sample project from Apple. It gives you a general idea of how to use `NSXMLParser`, and is also written to parse the XML data in its own thread to allow the user to still interact with the UI. If you are looking for a nested tag (i.e. `<body>` within `<item>`), you will want a flag to tell if you are currently within the `<item>` tag or not. Otherwise you will parse all `<body>` tags.

To address your second question, it depends on how you want to present this information to the user. If you want the text styled, you will need to use a UIWebView. Otherwise you can strip out what you need and have that spread out through a UITableView, or a custom view you create in Interface Builder.

**Edit:** After seeing your last comment, you need to create a flag (i.e. `insideBody`) and check for that inside of `foundCharacters:`

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    //NSLog(@"found characters: %@", string);
    // save the characters for the current item...
    if(insideBody == YES) {
        [currentBody appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [currentTitle appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [currentLink appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"summary"]) {
        [currentSummary appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
        [currentDate appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"dc:creator"]) {
        [currentCreator appendString:string];
    }
}
```

You will probably have to do the same in `didStartElement:` and `didEndElement:`, as getting data from `foundCharacters:` will only give you the content of tags and not the tags themselves.

Comment: I'm using the NSXMLParser already to get the the RSS, this is just for the `<body>` tag

Comment: Are you using an NSMutableString to construct the string inside the `<body>` tag? If memory serves, it should continue until the close of the tag (unless it encounters a tag inside which you are parsing for elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSXMLParser` to detect the `<body>` and `</body>` tags, and just grab everything between them into a string.

Now that I can see your code, I can see your bug. When you encounter the `<br />` tag you change the `currentElement` to `@"br"`, which means that you stop adding characters to `currentBody`.

Comment: I'm doing that already - the string does not contain everything, just until the first <br> witch is weird